# How to Execute ASP.Net MVC Ajax.ActionLink Only After Validation?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, actionlink

Net MVC 3.0 Project

I have a form in my page and a Ajax.ActionLink which adds another set of Fields to the current form, and this is a repetitive process, as long as user keeps clicking the ActionLink, it will keep adding more and more set of Fields to the form.

Here is my Ajax Action Link

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Add Another ERx", "ERxView", "Medication", new AjaxOptions
{
UpdateTargetId = "accordion",
InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter,
HttpMethod = "POST",
OnBegin = "destroyAccordion",
OnSuccess = "createAccordion"
}, new { @class = "standard button", id = "AnotherErx", onclick =  "document.ERxForm.submit();"})
```

My **Problem is**

When user clicks on the link it should first validate the current form for all required fields, upon successful validation only it should append the new set of Fields to the form.

I tried something like this in my Ajax.ActionLink to validate current form upon clicking the ActionLink

```
onclick =  "document.ERxForm.submit();"
```

this fires an Form Validation, But irrespective of Validation, it continues adding the new set of fields to the form.

Can any one help me, How can I achieve this

Thank for all who is taking time to read my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
OnBegin = "destroyAccordion"
```

Make destroyAccordion function call validation function and return true or fals.
If it is true then Action link executes.

Answer (score 1):

The issue most likely is that you are adding new elements to be validated.  If you add new validation elements via AJAX, it is necessary to clear and re-parse all validation attributes on the page, like so:

```
$("form").removeData("validator"); 
$("form").removeData("unobtrusiveValidation"); 
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse("form");
```

Add this to your `OnSuccess` function, and the validation will work for all elements on the page, original and added.

Comment: your answer helps me to an extent. But How can I make sure that my Controller action wont called until this validation is true.?

Comment: I missed that you are doing a submit as part of your ActionLink.  Why?  The submit interferes with the validation process.  I suggest removing the `onclick` event from the ActionLink, as I do not see what purpose it serves.  It definitely messes up the validation process.